# Schengen visa: appointment not available

Tags: schengen, international-travel, consulates, western-europe, schengen-visas

I and my husband are traveling to Italy, Switzerland and Netherlands in June. Our period of stay in Italy and Switzerland is almost the same, with 5N/6D in Switzerland and 6N/7D in Italy. Unfortunately, we are not able to find an appointment date at Italy consulate in SFO before our departure. Our flight and hotel reservations are done. We are wondering if we can take up visa appointment at Swiss consulate in SFO. If not, what are the chances of getting an emergency/expedited appointment at Italy consulate within 20 days of departure. Please help us here and let us know if it's possible to do so. Any suggestions would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: The embassies expect you to apply for your visas up to three months in advance. The chances of getting them to do an expedited appointment are slim otherwise people would abuse it. You may email them however chances are they will ignore you. You can tweak your days to spend one more day in Switzerland and then apply with them.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I think we'll add another day at Swiss and go to Swiss consulate.

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen states don't like to see "visa shopping" (the practice of applying to the "wrong" consulate in the hope of a better outcome).

However, you might have a little bit of leeway because the main purpose of the trip can be fuzzy. Are you doing anything in Switzerland that can be honestly called the main reason of the trip? If so, you can try to get your visa from the Swiss. Your application would say that you are going to Switzerland to see a museum or climb a mountain or whatever, and that you're seeing Italy and the Netherlands to see even more of Europe.

The risk would be that they reject your reasoning and refer you to the Italian consulate. Or, as Paul suggested, cut the stay in Italy by one day and extend the stay in Switzerland by one day.

Comment: They are applying in SFO (I assume through a VFS stateside). If so, they may qualify for premium expedite. It's part of the OP's question, please edit to include https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/applicationcentre.html with an explanation. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks o.m! We plan to hike Matterhorn in Switzerland although we are not sure if that can be taken as the main reason of trip without extending our stay in Swiss. We are thinking of adding another day in swiss and applying at swiss consulate to reduce the risks of rejection.

Comment: @Fow, There is no third party or VFS involved in getting schengen visa from Italian/Swiss consulate in US. Need to apply directly to the consulate and as of our research, chances of getting expedited appointment for tourism is slim.